# increase score of query where all text match and not repeating words

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the following query but it gets higher score for words which are repeated and is a subset of the words typed but not the entire sentence match.

For Eg:

```
{
  "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "test in maths",
            "fuzziness": "3",
            "fields": [
              "title"
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "75%",
            "type": "most_fields"
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

If the field value contains : **test test test**

has higher score than the field value : **test in maths**

How can I get the **higher score for the exact words match** and **not repeated words**?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search exact sentences/phrases you should use the match_phrase query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html).

You can add a should-clause that contains the match-phrase query to boost the score of exact phrases to your current query.

Comment: Please can write a sample query to the query above and shows us? Thank You n advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use match_phrase query for an exact match. **match_phrase** matches for exact occurrence in the sequence of the query provided.
e.g

```
{
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [{
                'match_phrase': {
                    'title': 'test in maths'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Editing after comment:

Use

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "index_options": "docs"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then you can use normal match type query, the elastisearch won't consider repetition of the words in the index for the title field.

Comment: We cannot use fuzziness here and we are looking at an exact match. Can we have fuzziness in exact match? Also, is there way to avoid exact_match as it might not be right all the time.

Comment: @jason use index_options mapping with docs as index_options, so your index won't consider the count of words while indexing. Updated the answer with example.